# Create new dictionory based on existing dictionories python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dictionaries as following

```
    d1 = {
'k1':[4,31,21],
'k2':[31,41,51],
'k3':[91,10,111]
}

d2 = {
'l1':11,
'l2':'21',
'l3':'31',
'l4':41
}
```

I want to return a new dictionary under the following conditions

- if the values of the d1 dictionary are present in the value of the d2 dictionary
  then I need to return a new dictionary with d1's key and d2's key.

for the above case, I need to return the following d3 dictionary

```
d3 = { k1=[l2,l3],k2=[l3,l4]}
```

here is what I have tried

```
  d3={}
  
  for key, val in d1.items():
    for x in val:

        if str(x) in d2:
            tmp = new_dict[str(x)]
            lst = d3[key] if key in d3 else list()
            lst.append(tmp)
            d3[key] = lst
```

Comment: does the `str(x)` needs to be in the key or the value of d2?

Comment: value of d2......

Comment: What was the problem with what you have tried?

Comment: getting an empty dictionory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to you can push it into one expression. Note: this expects all list values in `d1` to be integers.

```py
d = {k3: v3 for k3, v3 in ((k1, [k2 for k2, v2 in d2.items() if int(v2) in v1])
    for k1, v1 in d1.items()) if v3}
# {'k1': ['l2', 'l3'], 'k2': ['l3', 'l4']}
```

First you create a generator for the items that you will need where `k1` are the keys from `d1` and where you create the values with a list comprehension. Because it is possible that you get an empty list that you wish to drop, we use a generator of tuples. Only when we are sure that the list is not empty, we add it to the final dictionary.

Comment: Nice solution but boy if is difficult to understand

Comment: @AndiDomi Yeah, definitely not the most readable solution but probably one of the most efficient.

Comment: For python `3.8+`: `d3 = {k: l for k,v in d1.items() if (l:= [k2 for k2, v2 in d2.items() if int(v2) in v])}`

Answer (score 0):

1. Reverse d2

> d2_inverted = dict((d2[key], key) for (key, value) in d2.items())

2. Create d3

> ```
> d3={}   
> for (key, value) in d1.items():
>     print(key,value)
>     new_list = []
>     for element in value:
>         try:
>             new_list.append(d2_inverted[element])
>         except:
>             print("Unknows element")
>     # To remove empty list cases
>     if new_list:
>         d3[key] = new_list
> ```

Output

> ```
> print(d3)
> {'k1': ['l3', 'l2'], 'k2': ['l3', 'l4']}
> ```

Comment: this also outputs `'k3':[]` which may not be what OP was looking for as i did the same mistake and had to double check xD

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
d1 = {
'k1':[4,31,21],
'k2':[31,41,51],
'k3':[91,10,111]
}

d2 = {
'l1':11,
'l2':'21',
'l3':'31',
'l4':41
}

d3={}

for key, val in d1.items():
  a = []
  for x in val:
    for k, v in d2.items():
      if int(v)==int(x):
        a.append(k)
  print(a)
  if len(a):
    d3[key]=a
    
print(d3)
```

result
`{'k1': ['l3', 'l2'], 'k2': ['l3', 'l4']}`

Comment: i am getting something like this if this has float values `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'n'`